# Iterating through object types in a list of parent type

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I am trying to iterate through a list of objects and only change the ones that match a particular type. My current code looks like this. (Platform is an extension of Entity, and entities is a list of type Entity)

```
foreach (Platform p in entities.OfType<Platform>) { p.doStuff() }
```

I am getting the error "foreach cannot opperate on a 'method group'" Thanks for anyone's help. :)

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: You need to put `()` after `OfType<Platform>` but apart from that I can't see any problem.

Comment: Sorry should have included the error. Thanks.

Comment: In general the 'method group' error typically means you forgot parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright then :

```
foreach (Platform p in entities.OfType<Platform>())
 //Will loop through all object of Platform type in entites.OfType<Platform>()
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I don't know why I couldn't figure that out...

Comment: Seems odd, since it's the correct answer...

Comment: I hate being ninja downvoted for no reason.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Did I down vote something?

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ and the "is" and "as" keywords.

```
foreach (object o in entities.Where(x => x is Platform))
{
    Platform p = o as Platform;
    p.doStuff();
}
```

Comment: FYI missing a parenthesis on your foreach

Comment: Yeah, just saw it.  Ty!

Comment: That's cool. I haven't messed around with LINQ before. Thanks for the help!